# Keeping small projects on a single server via subdomains

Tags: php, web-services, iframe, dns

My goal is to have a development site: `mysite.com` which will host any small projects I have.  Two domains on GoDaddy (`fakedomain1.com` and `fakedomain2.com`) will pull their content from `fakedomain1.mysite.com`/`fakedomain2.mysite.com`. When someone goes to either fake domain the url will remain the same (`fakedomain1.com` or `fakedomain2.com`).

I saw two possible ways of accomplishing this. The first was using DNS settings, so I changed the '@' A record to the IP of my hosting server (which is dedicated). This actually worked, but then I removed my previously set up forwarding option to signup.fakedomain1 (which was used for a Launch Rock page) and it broke. Tried adding it back, but still nothing after multiple hours.

The second way I thought of doing this is with an iframe:

```
if($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == "fakedomain1.com") {
?>
    <html>

        <header>
            <title>Fake Domain</title>
        </header>

        <body style='margin: 0;'>
            <iframe src="<?php echo 'fakedomain1.mysite.com/'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>"  height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </body>

    </html>
<?php
}
```

But that's giving a 403 error, which I'm unsure of how to fix. I feel like doing this via DNS settings would be more proper.

Answer (score 0):

The first way(using DNS settings) looks fine. It must be a problem of [DNS Propagation](http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/wiki/dns-propagation/) that you are facing. It takes minimum of 24 hours for DNS records to update and propagate. You should wait for sometime and try again.